# GNUmake: how to write a true lambda

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, gnu-make

The following is my take on a so-so emulation of a lambda expression in GNUmake :

```
space := $(strip) $(strip)
comma := ,

# convert a space-separated list in $1 into a comma-separated list:
list2param = $(subst $(space),$(comma),$(strip $1))

# param $1 = quoted GUNmake expression
# param $2 = parameters to the expression as space-separated list
lambda = $(eval _lambda=$1)$(eval _lambda:=$$(call _lambda,$(call list2param,$2)))$(_lambda)
```

Example:

```
$(info $(call lambda,$$1 .. $$2 .. $$3,foo bar baz))
```

Output:

```
foo .. bar .. baz
```

But this is less than satisfying, as I have to use a variable "_lambda" behind the curtain and the mechanism isn't really like lambda as the evaluation isn't separated from the definition. Is there a clean, direct way to implement a lambda? Or is there already some mechanism implemented which my blind procedural programming eyes didn't catch?

Comment: What is your high-level problem?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin E.g. in a table sort I need to have a sorting key which I decided to pass as code: `$(info Sorting table: $(call sort_tbl,$(call select_from_MEMORY,1 2,where_name_FBL),3,$$(call lpad,$$(call lstrip,$$1,0x),8,0)))`. The `$$(call lpad ...` will take the element (a hex number) of column 1, strip the 0x prefix and left-pad it with 0's to create a key which is sortable for make.

Answer (score 0):

As in any primitive substitution language, you defer evaluation by quoting.  The example below looks horrible and doesn't let you nest lambdas, but otherwise works:

```
define lambda
$(eval lambda-f=$1)lambda-f
endef

$(foreach n,1 2 3,$(call $(call lambda,$$(info $$(shell seq -s ' ' $$1))),$n))
```

Some readability can be (arguably) regained by amending the syntax like this:

```
define lambda
$(eval lambda-f=$(subst ^,$$,$1))lambda-f
endef

$(foreach n,1 2 3,$(call $(call lambda,^(info ^(shell seq -s ' ' ^1))),$n))
```

Comment: With the two functions `# Count a binary literal up by 1 (e.g. 010011 -> 010100)

bincnt=$(if $1,$(if $(patsubst %1,,$1),$(patsubst %0,%1,$1),$(call bincnt,$(patsubst %1,%,$1))0),1)
# Generate a different symbol at each call

symgen = $(eval last_symgen:=sym$(call bincnt,$(subst sym,,$(last_symgen))))$(last_symgen)` one could generate different lambda-names at each invocation.